# Nextjs Smooth Scrolling

Tags: reactjs, next.js, smooth-scrolling

```
import { ReactLenis } from "@studio-freight/react-lenis";

function SmoothScrolling({ children }) {
  return (
    <ReactLenis root easing={(t) => Math.min(1, 1.001 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t))}>
      {children}
    </ReactLenis>
  );
}

export default SmoothScrolling;




import {SmoothScrolling} from '@/components/SmoothScrolling'
import '@/styles/globals.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return(
    <SmoothScrolling>
       <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SmoothScrolling>
  )
}
```

./node_modules/@studio-freight/react-lenis/dist/react-lenis.modern.mjs:1:0
Module not found: Default condition should be last one
Import trace for requested module:
./src/components/SmoothScrolling.jsx
./src/pages/_app.js

What's causing this error